# BigInteger in ForLoop and Lists in Java

Tags: java, list, for-loop, arraylist, biginteger

I am trying to create and return a BigInteger list that computes a given integer, `n`, as a sum of Fibonacci numbers in descending order. For example, if given the integer `n = 8000`, the result would return `[6765, 987, 233, 13, 2]`.

I have written a code that computes the Fibonacci numbers into a list while the said number is less than `n`, but I'm not quite how to implement the rest.

Comment: *Curious:* You're already using `BigInteger.ONE`, so why use `BigInteger.valueOf(1)`? And why use `BigInteger.valueOf(0)` instead of `BigInteger.ZERO`?

Comment: I was trying different ways to get the program to work, as I'm just learning Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print `fibs` you'll realize that you loop adds two 1's, so you should remove the `{fibs.add(BigInteger.ONE); fibs.add(BigInteger.ONE);}` line.

Now that you have all the Fibonacci number's, you start at the end of the list, and subtract numbers from `n` as long as the value doesn't go negative.

Easiest way to iterate a list backwards, is to reverse the list and iterate it normally.

```
Collections.reverse(fibs);
for (BigInteger fib : fibs) {
    ...
}
```

You can also do it without reversing the list, by using a `ListIterator` to iterate backwards.

```
for (ListIterator<BigInteger> iter = fibs.listIterator(fibs.size()); iter.hasPrevious(); ) {
    BigInteger fib = iter.previous();
    ...
}
```

To find the numbers you can subtract from `n`, just keep a running value of what still need to be reduced, i.e. how much of the original `b` *remains*.

```
BigInteger remain = n;
for (BigInteger fib : fibs) {
    if (fib.compareTo(remain) <= 0) {  // if (fib <= remain)
        remain = remain.subtract(fib); //   remain -= fib;
    }
}
```

Add the values you subtract to a result list, and you're done.

Comment: the first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are 1, and 1, so that's why the two 1's are added

Comment: @BeanieLeung But the `for` loop in your code also adds two 1's, so you end up with **four 1's** in `fibs`, as you would see if you did what I said, i.e. **print `fibs`**.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for pointing that out. So I added the values to a result list, but when I run the program, the last element returned in the list is a 0, which is very strange since 0 isn't an element is fibs. do you know why that would be?

Comment: i'm actually not even getting the correct results. right now when n = 1000000, this is the output : ```[167960, 46567, 199, 55, 0]```. I will update the code in the question so you can see what I have

Comment: @BeanieLeung Since I can't see your code, I wouldn't know. Given that `fib` inside that `if` statement in the loop would never be `0`, I have no idea what you did to get that result.

Comment: @BeanieLeung You're adding `remain`. You should be adding `fib`, i.e. "the values you subtract".

Answer (score 1):

The fib function seems too complicated to me. Just compute next element from sum of two last elements:

```
public static List<BigInteger> fib(BigInteger n) {
    List<BigInteger> fibs = new ArrayList<>(asList(ONE, ONE));
    for (BigInteger last = ONE; last.compareTo(n) < 0; ) {
        last = last.add(fibs.get(fibs.size() - 2));
        fibs.add(last);
    }
    return fibs;
}
```

Then go backwards in the list and keep elements which fit into sum:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger n = BigInteger.valueOf(8000);
    List<BigInteger> fib = fib(n);
    BigInteger remaining = n;
    for (int i = fib.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (fib.get(i).compareTo(remaining) > 0) {
            fib.remove(i);
        } else {
            remaining = remaining.subtract(fib.get(i));
        }
    }
    Collections.reverse(fib);
    System.out.println(fib);
}
```

Comment: why is there valueOf(19)?

Comment: @BeanieLeung That's just him testing with `n = 19` instead of `n = 1000000`

Comment: Want to up-vote, but result not "in descending order".

Comment: yes, 19 was just random test value, @Andreas thanks, I misread this requirement. Both fixed.